# There was an error completing your request Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I got this error! I cannot find any clue about the Service Outage. Is there anyone who have an idea about this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens sometimes. It automatically fixed after some hour. You can try after some hours and it will be ok. Also, you can check the status if you want in https://status.firebase.google.com.

Answer (score 1):

I am too late to answer but maybe it can help someone.

I had CORS turned On. Just turned it Off and works fine.

Comment: how do you turn off CORS?

Comment: You can ignore the auto-review comments: your answer does look just fine to me, but perhaps you could link to a resource that explains how you turned CORS off and if anything special needs to be done in the context of Firebase.

Comment: @PiedPiper the solution worked for me... So surely someone else would also be benefited.

Comment: @cutiko for hybrid app dev I need to enable CORS. I have a chrome extension for that, where I can turn on or off CORS

Comment: @ClausDue there is no documentation for that... I have spent hours to figure it out...